# google analytics - how to see the name of the pages which has been viewed by certain countries

Tags: google-analytics

I want a list of my site pages which has been viewed in any country.
I could not find such option in analytics.
How to do that.
So that i can know the people who view certain pages.
so that i can display content according to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to go to Content > Top Content (or content drilldown of whatever metric is best for the pages you wish to look at). Click the page you are interested in.

Then underneath "This page was viewed..." you will see a series of dropdown menus. Click the last one to see various metrics you can filter by. Click "Country/Territory" to see the most popular countries that visited that page.

One alternative: from the Top Content page, click the dropdown at the top of the table, next to "Page" and click "Country/Territory". This will list all pages and countries, by popularity. For example:

```
index.html        United States      999
about.html        United States      888
index.html        Canada             766
index.html        United Kingdom     421
about.html        Canada             123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom report. In your GA account click "Manage custom reports" then "create new report" under metric add the things you want to measure (visits, revenue, conversion rates etc.) under dimension add "Page title" for the first one then you can drill down under that with "country/territory" "region" or even "city". When you run the report you can see which pages are performing well, then select the page you are most interested in and you will see the stats by country/territory.

If you're looking to filter all reports by a specific country or group of countries you can use the advanced segments.